# Merge in entity manager do not works

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi all im using hibernate to manage my DB transactions, the find and createquery methods work good, but when I do a merge nothing happens, and any error is not displayed.

I´m trying to delete some Categorias from one Repositorio.
I change all the values correctly in the atribute

```
private List<ICategoria> categoriaList;
```

but in the merge I´m having the problem

This is my entity  Repositorio, a Repositorio  has many categories.

```
@Entity
public class Repositorio extends EntityBean implements IRepositorio {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String nome;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Categoria.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="repositorio")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<ICategoria> categoriaList;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public void incluirCategoria(ICategoria categoria) {

}
public void excluirCategoria(ICategoria categoria) {

}   
public List<ICategoria> getCategoriaList() {
    if (categoriaList == null) {
        categoriaList = new ArrayList<ICategoria>();
    }

    return categoriaList;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nome;
}

}
```

this is my entity  Categoria

```
@Entity
public class Categoria extends EntityBean implements ICategoria {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Documento.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categoria")
private List<IDocumento> documentoList;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Repositorio.class)
private IRepositorio repositorio;
private String nome;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Categoria.class)
private ICategoria categoria;//pai

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Categoria.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categoria")
private List<ICategoria> categoriaList;

public IRepositorio getRepositorio() {
    return repositorio;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public ICategoria getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}
public List<ICategoria> getCategoriaList() {
    if (categoriaList == null) {
        categoriaList = new ArrayList<ICategoria>();
    }

    return categoriaList;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.nome;
}

public List<IDocumento> getDocumentoList() {

    return documentoList;
}
public void setCategoria(ICategoria categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;     
}
public void setCategoriaList(List<ICategoria> categoriaList) {
    this.categoriaList = categoriaList;
}
@Override
public void setRepositorio(IRepositorio repositorio) {
    this.repositorio = repositorio;     
}
}
```

And this is my update method

```
public T update(T entity) {

    beginTransaction();
    T mergedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity); 
    entityManager.flush();
    commit();
    return mergedEntity;
}
```

**Update**

here is where I call the DAO to get my elements the method excluirCategoria is where I do the deleting of categories process

```
public class RepositorioFacade implements IRepositorioFacade {

    private IRepositorioDAO repositorioDAO;

    public List<IRepositorio> listar() {
        return getRepositorioDAO().list();
    }

    public IRepositorio criar() {
        return EntityBeanFactory.getRepositorio();      
    }

    public void excluir(IRepositorio repositorio) {
        getRepositorioDAO().delete(repositorio);        
    }

    public void gravar(IRepositorio repositorio) {
        getRepositorioDAO().save(repositorio);
    }       

    public void incluirCategoria(IRepositorio repositorio, ICategoria categoria) {      
        categoria.setRepositorio(repositorio);
        repositorio.getCategoriaList().add(categoria);      
    }

    public void excluirCategoria(IRepositorio repositorio, ICategoria categoria) {      
        while (categoria.getCategoriaList().size() > 0) {
            excluirCategoria(repositorio, categoria.getCategoriaList().get(0));
        }

        if (categoria.getCategoria() != null) {
            ICategoria catPai = categoria.getCategoria();

            if (catPai.getCategoriaList().indexOf(categoria) >= 0)
                catPai.getCategoriaList().remove(categoria);
        }

        if (repositorio.getCategoriaList().indexOf(categoria) >= 0) {
            repositorio.getCategoriaList().remove(categoria);   
        }
    }

    private IRepositorioDAO getRepositorioDAO(){
        if (repositorioDAO == null){
            repositorioDAO = DAOFactory.getRepositorioDAO();
        }

        return repositorioDAO;
    }


    @Override
    public void incluirSubCategoria(ICategoria categoriaPai, ICategoria categoriaFilho) {//(categoria selecionada e categoria nova (do pooup))
        categoriaFilho.setCategoria(categoriaPai);// 
        categoriaPai.getCategoriaList().add(categoriaFilho); //esto es para que el papa quede acctualizado pero para hibernate no se precisa
    }
    public IRepositorio find(int id){

        return DAOFactory.getRepositorioDAO().find(id);


    }
}
```

And this is my DAO where are the transactional methods  the list method fecth the element repository.

```
public class GenericDAO<T extends IEntityBean> {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WSysGED");
    protected EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    private void beginTransaction() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();     
    }

    private void commit() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }


    public GenericDAO(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void save(T entity) {                                
        if (entity.getId() == 0) {
            beginTransaction();
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            commit();
        } else {
            update(entity);
        }               
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        beginTransaction();
        entityManager.remove(entity);
        commit();       
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        System.out.println("update");       
        beginTransaction();
        T mergedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity); 
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
        commit();
        return mergedEntity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public T find(int entityID) {       
        return (T) entityManager.find(entityClass, entityID);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public T findReferenceOnly(int entityID) {
        return (T) entityManager.getReference(entityClass, entityID);       
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public List<T> list() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // query.getSingleResult()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T findOneResult(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        T result = null;

        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

            // Method that will populate parameters if they are passed not null and empty
            if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
                populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
            }

            result = (T) query.getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.out.println("No result found for named query: " + namedQuery);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while running query: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void populateQueryParameters(Query query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }       
}
```

**Update 2**

this is how I get all the categories from a respository

```
public TreeNode getRoot() {
    if (root == null) {
        List<ICategoria> listaCategorias = repositorio.getCategoriaList();

        root = new DefaultTreeNode(null);
        TreeNode noInicial = new DefaultTreeNode("Categorias", root);

        for (ICategoria categoria : listaCategorias) {
            if (categoria.getCategoria() == null) {
                TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(categoria, noInicial);
                incluirNoFilho(categoria, node);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Thanks in adavance for your time and answers

Comment: Turn on `show sql` in hibernate to see what kind (if any) of sql is executed when you are commiting transaction. Moreover, you don't have to flush entity manager (if it is JPA Entity manager) before commiting, as commit will do it anyway. Can you please show us transaction management methods as well?

Comment: I activated the sql log but in that operation nothing happens. what do you mean with transaction management methods? @Antoniossss

Comment: I mean your `beginTransaction();` and `commit();` Nothing is happening because your changes are ommited, probably due the fact I have pointed out in my answer. Show code for fetching category and removing documents from it as well

Comment: I made an update to the question. See one Repositorio have many categories, the method excluirCategoria is the method to delete one category from the repository

Comment: Should you close the entityManger after commit? its just like session in hibernate, you close the session after you are done using it

Comment: in this project i do some calls to  save method and never needed to close the entityManger. @Zeus

Answer (score 0):

Straight from JPA 2.0 documentation about `merge`

```
The persistence provider must not merge fields marked LAZY that have not been fetched: it must ignore
such fields when merging.
```

As your documents are LAZY LOADED you would have fetch them with your main entity first, otherwise changes made to collections will be ommited. However, I am curious why it is not working becouse you should have fetched collections (LAZY WAY) to remove some entities from it, so the collection should be fetched by proxy anyway. Could you please show us the code where you fetch and manipulate such collection?

Comment: for testing purposes I deleted the lazy anotation and nothing happens @Antoniossss

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after many reasearch I realized that in the anotation I miss that

```
(orphanRemoval=true)
```

so now  my code looks like this

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Categoria.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categoria")
private List<ICategoria> categoriaList;
```

that is the solution